# How to accept Android licenses

Tags: flutter

> Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 26.0.2) !
>   Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter
>   doctor --android-licenses

It gives error reading dependency file and then flutter crashes. Is it something to do with dart to or am i missing something here?

Comment: In Android Studio, you should check to ensure that the Android SDK Command-line Tools are installed. Adding this fixed the issue for me in Flutter. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67791870/8094969

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As it says in the message:

`To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses`

Comment: i cant run flutter doctor

Comment: i ran fluttere doctor and accepted all but still the same issue.

Answer (score 8):

In your **flutter folder** you can find **flutter_console.bat**.

[image]

**Open it and write the following:**

- **flutter doctor --android-licenses**[image]

Comment: I did this already and accepted all the licenses and All SDK package licenses accepted. But finish with error: Gradle build failed: 1

Comment: Check if you have the added route of Dart SDK and Flutter SDK

Comment: i created another project, and it runs perfectly ok, builds gradle and etc, but this error occurs only at one particular project but the thing that i don't understand is that it does not show any error in my code.

Comment: After this, close and reopen Android Studio

Answer (score 5):

You have to run an elevated command prompt in order to accept the license. Go to the windows start menu, type `CMD` then right click the `Command Prompt` and select `Run as Administrator`. This will start the command line with elevated priviliges.

[image]

Comment: This is the right answer if you see this line: ` Warning: File C:\Users\XXX\.android\repositories.cfg could not be loaded.`

Answer (score 1):

In my case flutter doctor command didn't help me, Flutter used default project SDK in
[image] C Drive: **C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk** which is missing licenses folder, But I use different SDK for building application which has licenses folder I copied that to `C Drive SDK` then the problem has solved then Flutter app got installed in the mobile.