# Can't accept Android Licenses (Flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sdk, licensing

Well, a month ago I was learning a bit of Flutter, and it was all fine, no problems, so, last week I lost everything in my PC, and need to format it, I did. So yesterday I tried install Flutter but, when accepting Android Licenses, it gave me this error:

`Warning: File /home/damiani/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.`

To solve this i just `touch .android/repositories.cfg` and this message doesnt appear anymore, but now, when I `flutter doctor --android-licenses` it gave me this:

`[=========                              ] 25% Fetch remote repository...`

From this, I can't do anything, it just get stucked in there... Sometimes even give this:

`[=============================          ] 75% Computing updates...`

Or this:

`[=======================                ] 58% Computing updates...`

The longer it gets is here:

```
1 of 6 SDK package license not accepted.] 100% Computing updates...             
Review license that has not been accepted (y/N)? y

1/
```

And from there, this message doesn't change...

When doing `flutter doctor -v`:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.14.7-pre.120, on Linux, locale pt_BR.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 1.14.7-pre.120 at /home/damiani/flutter
    • Framework revision 82c00c915c (3 hours ago), 2020-02-05 06:35:49 -0800
    • Engine revision 81dffd1241
    • Dart version 2.8.0 (build 2.8.0-dev.7.0 c8ed304e97)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /home/damiani/Android/Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: /var/lib/snapd/snap/android-studio/82/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /var/lib/snapd/snap/android-studio/82/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 43.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

No mood to continue with Flutter. Thanks since now...

*sorry for bad english*

*os: arch linux*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter run error : You have not accepted the license agreements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48604914/flutter-run-error-you-have-not-accepted-the-license-agreements)

Comment: I do no have the answer but ... I do have the same problem in Archlinux.
I do not think it is an Arch problem though, because in my office I have another Arch box and it works fine. But, so far I have not been able to figure out the reason it does not work.

Comment: Ralvez, I solved the problem parcially, I removed all Java JDK installed (except the one with Android Studio) and installed Java 7, later I just runned ./Android/Sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager (I dont remember the exact path), accepted the licenses, and it worked, flutter doctor runs no issue. BUT, ever I run a flutter project I need to do flutter run on terminal, cause somehow acceleration doesn't work anymore, so, its not 100% solved, for a simple project, may be fine. I think thats a linux firmware problem, cause I tried with popOS and Mint (kernel 5.3), and had no problems...

Comment: In Android Studio, you should check to ensure that the Android SDK Command-line Tools are installed. Adding this fixed the issue for me in Flutter. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67791870/8094969

Answer (score 1):

switching to flutter dev channel fixed the problem for me. run 
`flutter channel dev` and then `flutter upgrade` and try 
`flutter doctor --android-licenses`

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the following commands,(It should ask you to accept the licenses)

```
sdkmanager --licenses
```

And also make sure to run the following

```
flutter config --android-sdk /pathToAndroidSdk --android-studio-dir /pathToAndroidStudio
```

After the above two commands I hope your problem should be resolved.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because you haven't accepted all the android licenses.

Follow these steps, this worked for me.

1. Open console/terminal
2. Type flutter doctor `--android-licenses`
3. Accept every license that comes up, press `y` and you are good to go.