# Flutter : can't accept android licenses

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-licenses

When I'm running `flutter doctor`, I was found 1 issue: X Android license status unknown.

> C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat doctor --verbose [√] Flutter (Channel
> stable, 2.0.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.264], locale
> en-US)
> • Flutter version 2.0.1 at C:\src\flutter
> • Framework revision c5a4b4029c (6 days ago), 2021-03-04 09:47:48 -0800
> • Engine revision 40441def69
> • Dart version 2.12.0
>
> [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
> version 30.0.3)
> • Android SDK at C:\Users\Mariam Younes\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
> • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
> • ANDROID_HOME = C:/Users/Mariam Younes/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk
> • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
> X Android license status unknown.
> Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
> See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for
> more details.
>
> [√] Chrome - develop for the web
> • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
>
> [√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
> • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
> • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
> https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
> • Dart plugin can be installed from:
> https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
>
> [√] VS Code (version 1.54.1)
> • VS Code at C:\Users\Mariam Younes\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
> • Flutter extension version 3.20.0
>
> [√] Connected device (2 available)
> • HUAWEI CUN U29 (mobile) • CCMBBCB780348362 • android-arm    • Android 5.1 (API 22)
> • Chrome (web)            • chrome           • web-javascript • Google Chrome 89.0.4389.82
>
> ! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

And when I'm trying to run `flutter doctor --android-licenses`, this error happens:

> C:\Users\Mariam Younes\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app>flutter
> doctor --android-licenses Error: Could not find or load main class we

Can any one show me where is my error ?

Comment: In Android Studio, you should check to ensure that the Android SDK Command-line Tools are installed. Adding this fixed the issue for me in Flutter. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67791870/8094969

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, `flutter doctor --android-licenses` didn't work for some reason.

The only command that worked & solved the issue was:

`(your android_sdk folder exact path)\tools\bin\sdkmanager --licenses`

Answer (score 0):

install android sdk command line tools from
Android studio-> preferences-> appearance & Behaviours -> System Setting -> Android Sdk -> android sdk tools -> android Sdk Command line tools make it check and apply.
After that you can run your command.