# Error after running flutter doctor : Unable to locate Android SDK

Tags: flutter, android-studio, sdk, flutter-test

I got these errors after installing flutter then running flutter doctor to check if the installation succeeded, Although I've installed both Android Studio and Android SDK in Android Studio's installation progress steps with no issues at all, what do I have to do now?

[image: Click here to show the image!]

Comment: Is your flutter application not rinning?

Comment: In Android Studio, you should check to ensure that the Android SDK Command-line Tools are installed. Adding this fixed the issue for me in Flutter. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67791870/8094969

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using android studio, try these steps :

1. Click Tools > SDK Manager.
2. In the SDK Platforms tab, select Android 10 (29).
3. In the SDK Tools tab, select Android SDK Build-Tools 29 (or higher).
4. Click OK to begin install.

In case if above steps don't solve your problem then try updating the SDK path

```
flutter config --android-sdk <path-to-your-android-sdk-path>
```

Note: path must be enclosed within double quotes

```
"C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk"
```

Comment: I tried them all but when I tried to change the path it tells me the syntax of the command is incorrect.

Comment: I have fixed the Androd toolchain - develop for Android devices error, but still have the Android Studio (not installed) error one left.

Comment: Fixed them both by using flutter config --android-studio-dir <path-to-your-android-studio-path> in addition to Niteesh's answer for path of sdk