# Flutter error for Android license status unknown

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I tried to run flutter on my Windows 10 and getting some errors. Trying to resolve error " Android license status unknown." from the last couple of hours. But no luck. My system environment is like the followings:

> Windows 10, java version "12.0.2" 2019-07-16, Android Studio 3.5.

Can anyone know the thing which I am missing here?

```
C:\Users\me>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.885], locale en-US)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed
      instructions.
[!] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.37.1)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.

C:\Users\me>
```

I tried the following command (**flutter doctor --android-licenses**) and getting the errors like this:

```
C:\Users\me>flutter doctor --android-licenses
A newer version of the Android SDK is required. To update, run:
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager --update



C:\Users\me>
```

Comment: did you get solution of it? it's same issue for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I set JDK_HOME and then run the following command to fix:

**`flutter doctor --android-licenses`**

So, basically it was unable to configure JDK home and that error occurred. Hopefully, it will solve issues if you face this error.

Answer (score 2):

Did you already accepted the licenses?
If not, try

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

As shown in [How to accept Android licenses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50706353/how-to-accept-android-licenses)

Comment: Tried this from but getting errors::C:\Users\me>flutter doctor --android-licenses
A newer version of the Android SDK is required. To update, run:
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager --update



C:\Users\me>

Answer (score 0):

Actually The Android License is not necessary to do. Just open the android studio and start a new flutter project and have fun! If you want to do so. Type the command: flutter doctor --android-licenses 
Have Fun!

Comment: yeah, just have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Its worked me..

So here the solution, open your SDK manager then uncheck `Hide Obsolete Packages`

[image]

Now you’ll see `Android SDK Tools (Obsolete) 26.1.1` appears. Tick that package and hit `apply button` then ok button. it will download sdk.
then `restart` Android studio

Nice, now if you run `flutter doctor`, you should get positive result as below

```
PS D:\Workplace\flutter_projects> flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.657], locale en-MY)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[√] VS Code (version 1.42.1)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!

PS D:\Workplace\flutter_projects> flutter doctor --android-licenses -v
All SDK package licenses accepted.======] 100% Computing updates...
```

Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` and enter Y when is asked

Refer--https://robbinespu.gitlab.io/blog/2020/03/03/flutter-issue-fixed-android-license-status-unknown-on-windows/

if needed we can download package manually here https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip (for Windows user). Hope this tutorial help people who looking for solution